# Missing Partial Error in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting an error:

```
Missing partial post/questions, application/questions with
{:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}.
Searched in:* "/Users/..../<project name>/app/views"
```

I tried to render all posts in the database to `index.html.erb`.

My view part is `post/index.html.erb`:

```
    <!--html codes -->

    <%= render 'questions' %>
```

Controller `controller/post_controller.rb`:

```
    def index
       @posts=Post.all
    end

    def questions
    end
```

`questions.html.erb`

```
    <%=@posts.each do |post| %>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h2>
                    <%=post.title%>
                </h2>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3><%=post.body%></h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                This Post comes under:<h4><%=post.tag%></h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Partials' file names must begin with an underscore. You should have _questions.html.erb saved in the post folder. Also, you don't need to define a 'questions' action.

Comment: had similar problem ... forgot the .html.erb extensions.  .rb doesn't work lol